Lenovo Yoga Pro 9i: graphics Issues and boot failures on Ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10
Four months ago I bought a Lenovo Yoga Pro 9i 16 Gen 9 16IMH9, with Intel Core Ultra 9 and RTX 4070, on which I installed both Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 with the default 6.8 kernel.
As you can see here, on Ubuntu there were often graphic problems: part of the screen changed color, or some letters disappeared. I noticed that it happened more with many writings on the screen (e.g. Gmail, Matlab, VSCode). This problem never occurred on Windows.

Some days ago I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.10, hoping that the new 6.11 kernel would fix it, but it didn't.
In return, now I have another problem, as Ubuntu not always boots correctly after being selected it in the GRUB. About once out of four, the screen becomes black and it doesn't even let me open a terminal with CTRL+Alt+Fx. The only thing I can do is to switch it off and try again, if it were not that the power button broke after a few uses, so in these cases the only thing I can do is to wait for the battery to run out. Now I'm currently working without a battery in order to avoid breaking it.
I tried to reinstall Windows, 24.04 and 24.10 different times, but the problem still remains.
